# Close all but this with autohotkey

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I find the "close all but this" is really useful for me in a lot of cases. So are there anyway to close all applications running by this user, but not the active application. Hide could be a option with another hotkey.

Thanks much :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an AutoHotkey script try this.

http://www.autohotkey.net/~joeshmoo/CloseOtherWindows_0.1.ahk

If you're already running Windows 7, you won't need another AHK script. You can minimize/hide other windows EXCEPT the active window by pressing <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>HOME</kbd> or doing the [Aero-shake](http://youtu.be/CNIB6yXh7DI) (click & hold the title bar of the window and then shake it).

Comment: This one closes the same type windows only. What I want is all windows :D. But I think I can work this script to what I want. Thanks

Comment: The link's broken.